# Apollo GraphQL Server - Access query params from cache plugin

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have an Apollo GraphQL server using the `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache` plugin and I need to determine whether or not I'm going to write to the cache based on incoming parameters. I have the plugin set up and I'm using the `shouldWriteToCache` hook. I can print out the `GraphQLRequestContext` object that gets passed into the hook, and I can see the full request source, but `request.variables` is empty. Other than parsing the `query` itself, how can I access the actual params for the resolver in this hook? (In the example below, I need the value of `param2`.)

Apollo Server:

```
new ApolloServer({
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
    subscriptions: false,
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    cacheControl: {
        defaultMaxAge: 60
    },
    plugins: [
        apolloServerPluginResponseCache({
            cache,  // This is a "apollo-server-cache-redis" instance
            shouldWriteToCache: (requestContext) => {
                
                // I get a lot of info here, including the source query, but not the 
                // parsed out query variables
                console.log(requestContext.request);
                
                // What I want to do here is:
                return !context.request.variables.param2
                // but `variables` is empty, and I can't see that value parsed anywhere else
            }
        })
    ]
})
```

Here is my resolver:

```
export async function exapi(variables, context) {
  // in here I use context.param1 and context.param2
  // ...
}
```

I have also tried:

```
export async function exapi(variables, { param1, param2 }) {
  // ...
}
```

Here is what I get logged out from the code above:

```
{
  query: '{\n' +
    '  exapi(param1: "value1", param2: true) {\n' +
    '    records\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '}\n',
  operationName: null,
  variables: {},            // <-- this is empty?! How can I get param2's value??
  extensions: undefined,
  http: Request {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    follow: 20,
    compress: true,
    counter: 0,
    agent: undefined,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: null, disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Request internals)]: {
      method: 'POST',
      redirect: 'follow',
      headers: [Headers],
      parsedURL: [Url],
      signal: null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you didn't provide `variables` for GraphQL query, you could get the arguments from the GraphQL query string via [ArgumentNode](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/4b7ab47c3f4ea6be99c3d9754b21fe626f7c7177/src/language/ast.d.ts#L272) of AST
2. If you provide `variables` for GraphQL query, you will get them from `requestContext.request.variables`.

E.g.

`server.js`:

```js
import apolloServerPluginResponseCache from 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { RedisCache } from 'apollo-server-cache-redis';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    exapi(param1: String, param2: Boolean): String
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    exapi: (_, { param1, param2 }) => 'teresa teng',
  },
};

const cache = new RedisCache({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });

const server = new ApolloServer({
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  subscriptions: false,
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  cacheControl: {
    defaultMaxAge: 60,
  },
  plugins: [
    apolloServerPluginResponseCache({
      cache,
      shouldWriteToCache: (requestContext) => {
        console.log(requestContext.document.definitions[0].selectionSet.selections[0].arguments);
        return true;
      },
    }),
  ],
});
server.listen().then(({ url }) => console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`));
```

GraphQL query:

```
query{
  exapi(param1: "value1", param2: true) 
}
```

Server logs print `param1` and `param2` arguments:

```
 Server ready at http://localhost:4000/
[]
[ { kind: 'Argument',
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'param1', loc: [Object] },
    value:
     { kind: 'StringValue',
       value: 'value1',
       block: false,
       loc: [Object] },
    loc: { start: 15, end: 31 } },
  { kind: 'Argument',
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'param2', loc: [Object] },
    value: { kind: 'BooleanValue', value: true, loc: [Object] },
    loc: { start: 33, end: 45 } } ]
```

Comment: Wow... ok, so using `requestContext.document.definitions[0].selectionSet.selections[0].arguments` does work, thanks! But any idea why `requestContext.request.variables` is still empty? Just to be clear: the first path _does_ have my arguments, but `request.variables` does not for the **same** gql call.

Comment: I added my resolver (and your suggested change) to the question above. I still do not get anything in `request.variables` (but I can use your AST suggestion)

Comment: @JordanKasper Maybe my answer is not clear. If you want to get `request.variables`, you should send GraphQL query with a `variables`. Check this link: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Oooh... my mistake, I see now that this is entirely different. Thanks again.